# Attempting to Keep GMSMarkers loaded in the background

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, marker

How to keep Google Maps markers loaded in the background after I transition to a new view?

I currently have to retrieve objects from my server every time my map view is brought to view again, due to not being able to save my markers on the map.

I am sending my MapView, the markerID values, the markers themselves, and their icons in between ViewControllers, however, the GMSMapView is always free of markers although I'm sending the variables and arrays with it.

Comment: Are you adding marker on main thread.

Comment: can you please provide code overview what you are doing ??